# How to get less 403 and more 200 response while Web Scraping in python request using proxy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-multithreading, http-proxy

I'm working on a research project for which I need to scrape some URLs. I have over 5k URLs of foursquare (like this one: https://foursquare.com/v/t-spesjalleke/4c94ec0d533aa09384d5c345) from which I just need to know if the restaurant is cheap/moderate/expensive/very expensive. So I've written a script where I'm parsing 50 proxy from https://free-proxy-list.net for each foursquare request. I'm using random.choice() from the proxy list for request until I'm getting response code 200. After getting the 200 response code using beautiful soup to get the category and writing it to a file. But the problem is I'm getting 403 code a lot. And that's why it is taking so much time for each request. So I tried concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) to make it faster but it's not making that faster as I'm getting lots of 403 responses. And I'm using the header agent also for request.

This is the script I'm trying to run: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/j3FYGngMGS/

I need to make the process optimal. I'm not finding any other solutions. Please provide some insights which might help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To get less 403 authenticate yourself ;)

Comment: How to do that? Can you please explain?

Comment: The answer is relative and too broad you should learn about authentication generally you are authenticated using token in request header. Looking at your question looks like you are a beginner, please try to implement authenticating an api to understand how it works

Comment: use the [Foursquare api](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api)

Comment: Yes, I'm a beginner. Ok, I'll try to learn the authenticating an API. Thanks a lot. But one last question, so there is no way to scrap data from those URLs without using foursquare API???

Comment: I've tried using there API. But with free API rate limit is too low. Now I'm getting 429 code that my daily quota is gone. Now, what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Is this a IP location problem? you could be getting the error due to the IP not matching the country that the website owner has set.

Another could be IP blacklisting, although you have the pool of proxies, these aren't private, thus others could have used them and got them listed.